# Pixhawk 4 vs Hex Cube Orange on Auterion platform

Tags: px4

I would like to know if Hex Cube Orange is compatible with software developed on auterion. I know that pixhawk 4 is compatible, but since Hex cube has a better CPU, I'm more leaned to choose hex cube. Regarding the project, this is a company project to make a new drone (octopter), and the CEO wants to use a flight controller for development only, like research, before using the definitive flight controller. But since there is this doubt, we don't want to order the flight controller without knowing if it works on auterion. I already contacted Auterion, but no response yet.

This question is made taken into account what is on px4.io site regarding both flight controllers. The hex cube orange is experimental and community supported while the pixhawk 4 is optimized to use px4.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without doing some deep research it would appear that the Hex Cube Orange is compatible with Auterion. It may require compilation for the target. But uses the PX4 kernel.

The Hex Cube has been around for a while. The Orange is just an updated version of their other products. It has a larger microcontroller with more memory and replaced some components that have reached end of life.

The Pixhawk 4 and the Cube Orange have many components in common and both support either PX4 or Ardupilot software.